# Suddenly Blender 2.8 doesn't start

Tags: startup-file

I've been using Blender 2.8 until yesterday then today i wasn't able to open it again. Tried to do a clean install and it still doesn't open. I've tried to run it with --debug-gpu and --factory-startup or --debug-all but the command line simply remains completely empty. I've also updated GPU drivers with no success.

System : 
Windows 10, 
Graphics Card RX580 8GB,
Blender 2.8

Any kind of help would be appreciated since i'm quite lost honestly, i've also tried to download and use 2.79 and it starts correctly but after a single click in the viewport the program freezes

Comment: Hi @Davide, please note that this question is off-topic for [blender.se], questions relating to support should be directed to an appropriate forum or try https://blender.chat.  The problem is likely something you have installed / uninstalled / drivers hence it being out of scope for this [SE] site which deals specifically with creation using blender.  I hope this is some help to you , good luck with your issue.

Comment: thanks Merlin, going to ask in the chat